# Contact form doesnt send the message

Tags: php, html

My contact form in php doesnt send the message to the mail so i need to know whats the problem here 
You will find the html form here with file name : index.php
and php form with name : mail.php

```
<form class="form" action="mail.php" method="post" name="contactform">
    <input class="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name">
    <input class="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" >
    <input class="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone No:" name="phone">
    <textarea class="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Message"name="message"  ></textarea>
    <input class="submit-btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From:  phone'; 
    $to = 'modysaid26@gmail.com'; 
    $subject = 'message';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Phone Number: $phone\n Message:\n $message";

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
            echo '<p>Your message has been submitted</p>';
        } else { 
            echo '<p>Something went wrong, please try again!</p>'; 
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Try add the $email to $from. Here is a similar contact form that it works: https://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/simple-contact-form-script

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="submit-btn" name='submit' type="submit" value="Submit">
```

You are missing to add the name to submit button so your case `if (isset($_POST['submit']) ) {` fails

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to put name on the form tag remove the class either:
 `<form action="mail.php" method="post">`

Answer (score 0):

First yor submit button name is missing, please use a

```
<input class="submit-btn" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
```

The second you email command ( `mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)` ) has no right email header. Insead your `$from`
please define header with following parameters

```
$email_headers = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_email.">\r\n".
"Reply-To: ".$reply_to."\r\n" ;
if ($cc) $email_headers.="Cc: ".$cc."\r\n";
if ($bcc) $email_headers.="Bcc: ".$bcc."\r\n";
$email_headers.="MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n" .
"Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

$email_body=$_POST['message'];
```

and then send it using

```
mail($to, $subject, $email_body, $email_headers);
```

And then your email shouldbe send properly.

Comment: where's the email_body in the defined code ?

Comment: My mistake ..., at $email_body just put the content from your message input like $email_body=$_POST['message'];